# Search files in Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, search, google-sites

I am trying to implement the following code into my Google site so that I can search files in my Google drive by typing any parameters into the search bar, but I am getting the below error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property "parameter" from undefined. (line 2,
> file "Search")"

error when I try to run it in Google script compiler.
I know this error means that the parameter didn't set to any value. So I tried test with implementing it into a new Google site page but still get no search result.

```
function doGet(e) {
      var results = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B3xR7WfXrj7aQTc5NWNMOGtITGc').searchFiles('fullText contains "' + e.parameter.q + '"');
      var app = UiApp.createApplication();
      var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
      while(results.hasNext()) {
        var file = results.next();
        panel.add(app.createAnchor(file.getName(), file.getUrl()));
      }
      var scrollPanel = app.createScrollPanel(panel).setHeight(200);
      app.add(scrollPanel);
      return app;
    }
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your method of "GET"?

Comment: GET is used here for to do HTTP servlet request

Comment: If now you run this script on the script editor, an error occurs. Because it hasn't got the value using GET. If you want to test this script, you need to deploy a script as a web app. You can check it here. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web After you deployed this script, if it didn't work. Please confirm about GET method.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I found out that Google deprecated `UiApp()` class. I had to use HTML service instead.
Here is the working code:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var results = DriveApp.getFolderById('youGoogleDriveId').searchFiles('fullText contains "' + e.parameter.q + '"');
  var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Results: <br /><br /><ul>');
  while (results.hasNext()) {
    var file = results.next();
    output.append('<li><a href="' + file.getUrl() + '">' + file.getName() + '</a></li>');
  }
  output.append('</ul>');
  return output;
}
```

But I get no result on the files that they are in sub-folders. I haven't figure it out yet doing search on all the files in the drive -even under sub-folders.